# How to reference websites using bibliography style ieeetr?

Tags: bibliographies

I have in my list.bib file a reference:

```
@misc{DonoraSmog,
author = {Wikipedia},
title = {1948 Donora Smog},
month = jun,
year = {2009},
url = {http://www.test.org/doe/}
}
```

But, once compiled, it does not show the website in the pdf. I am using the package {url}.

Also, is there a package that does APA citing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(too long for comment)

With the following code, the website is displayed.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sampbib.bib}
  @misc{DonoraSmog,
author = {Wikipedia},
title = {1948 Donora Smog},
month = jun,
year = {2009},
url = {http://www.test.org/doe/}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{url}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \bibliography{sampbib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If this code doesn't work for you as such, you may have to provide your code for testing.

Comment: My document class is article, is that a big deal? And I am using an external .bib file.

Comment: @CivilSigma As long as we don't know it, it is `;-)`. My code above works with article class too. And I am using external bib file too.

Comment: Oh wow! I just typed \nocite{DonoraSmog} and all my sources displayed their respective urls. LaTeX is even weirder than computer programming! Thank you for your help Mr.Kumar :D

Comment: Any idea how I can center "References" ?

Comment: @CivilSigma Add these lines to your preamble: `\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{\section*{\hfil\refname}}{}{}`